# How to install python3.8 on ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu-18.04

I have Jetson nano 4gb and when I installed the .iso image file from [jetson nano getting started page](https://developer.nvidia.com/embedded/learn/get-started-jetson-nano-devkit#write) it comes with ubuntu 18.04 and python 3.6.9.

Plenty of websites suggested to use deadsnakes repo :[text](https://launchpad.net/%7Edeadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa). There is no supported python3.8 for ubuntu 18.04.

I didn't find any suitable repositories.Because of the libraries that I use, I have to install python 3.8 or above. I also try to install ubuntu 20.04 on Jetson but it caused problems about CUDA.Do you have any suggestions?I have to use ubuntu 18.04 and python 3.8 and above. I really cannot find any solution.

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)